# Why isnt this object null after a shallow copy?

Tags: c#, shallow-copy

Below is my copy of spouse to client (both are same object type). 
Spouse is then set to null.

```
client = spouse; // Copying data
spouse = null;
```

I then pause (using a breakpoint on a different line) and check the memory of client and spouse. spouse is null, however client isn't.

Shouldn't client be null because its memory is a result of a *shallow copy*?

Cheers

Comment: It is not doing a shallow copy. If `client` and `spouse` are reference types (i.e., if they're an instance of a class), you are changing *pointers*, not copying data. And even if it *did* do a shallow copy, one would expect `client` not to be null, as it is a copy of the original spouse

Comment: To add to that, the only time that functionality would occur in 'Normal C#' would be for `ref` parameters.

Comment: Correct, they are reference types. Thanks Rob. I would mark this as the answer but its a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't happen because you are changing the value of the *pointers*, not the object itself.

Let's imagine this scenario:

```
var spouse = new Person(); //Let's say the memory address of this new person is 0x000010
```

Now, we have this:

```
Person client = null; //The pointer of client now points to 0x000000

client = spouse;      //The pointer of client now points to 0x000010

spouse = null;        //The pointer of spouse now points to 0x000000
                      //However - client has *not* changed, it still points to 0x000010
                      //and the object still remains in memory.
```

Answer (score 13):

Your spouse lives at 123 Sesame Street.

You write down on a piece of paper: SPOUSE: 123 Sesame Street.

Now you write down on another piece of paper: CLIENT:.  Then you copy whatever it says after SPOUSE on the first piece of paper.

Now you have two pieces of paper. One says "SPOUSE: 123 Sesame Street". The other says "CLIENT: 123 Sesame Street".

Now you erase the address on the page that says SPOUSE.

What does the page that says CLIENT now say?

---

Your confusion is apparent in your choice of jargon.

Do not say "makes a shallow copy". Say "copies a reference", because that's what you're doing. "Shallow" is relative without saying relative to what. Say what is really happening: the value is being copied and *the value is a reference*.

Do not say "this object is null".  That's like saying "the car in my driveway that is not there"; it's nonsensical. A *variable* can *contain* a null reference.  A *reference* can be a *null reference*; it is the reference that refers to no object. But it is not an object; it is the absence of an object.

When you make your language precise then these sorts of confusions start to drop away rapidly.

Answer (score -3):

The way you are using to Shallow copy is not the proper way in C#. C# provide us a function we can use to perform a shallow copy. the function is `MemberwiseClone()`.

Try this

```
Client = Spouse.MemberwiseClone();
```

Please tell me if it doesn't work for you.
cheers

Comment: you can also refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` is a protected method, this will only work if written inside the class which `Spouse` is an instance of.